# PHP-MySQL. How to show the result in group for this kind of situation?

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL table, i have data like this

```
date    | count
3-15(0) |   6  
3-15(1) |   10
3-15(2) |   9
3-16(0) |   1
3-16(2) |   12
3-17(1) |   13
3-18(0) |   23
```

I want to add up the "count" column grouped by "date" column like:

```
3-15 : 25
3-16 : 13
3-17 : 13
3-18 : 23
```

Can you tell me how to fetch and group this way?

Comment: I don't understand the figures in parentheses

Comment: Something like that? `SELECT COUNT(blackout_instance_id) my_count, start_date FROM blackout_instances GROUP BY start_date`

Comment: @Strawberry the figures in parenthesis are just integers 0~2.

Comment: Why are they in a date column? That seems odd - and very inefficient.

Comment: @Strawberry I tried implementing counter using php-mysql. Like a visitor counter per day. The reason why I have date+(integer) is to avoid bottleneck slow-down by having several 'keys'.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the  [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) using substring function. remove string after `(` and use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) clause to sum of all count

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`date`, '(', 1), SUM(`count`) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`date`, '(', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your 'date' column contains strings, you could group by the string before the first occurrence of '(':

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, '(', 1),
    SUM(count)
FROM
    yourtable
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, '(', 1)
```